# why value 1 is been inserted in database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is my piece of code data of form has to inserted in database but everytime i submit the form only value 1 is being inserted in each column

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if($con)  {
        mysql_select_db("college",$con);
    } else  {
        echo "Connection is not Est"."<br>";
    }

    $first_name=isset($_POST['first_name']);
    $middle_name=isset($_POST['middle_name']);
    $last_name=isset($_POST['last_name']);
    $email_id=isset($_POST['email_id']);
    $mobile_no=isset($_POST['mobile_no']);

    //  if($first_name!=""){                            
    $qry=mysql_query("insert into stud_master(fname,mname,lname,mobile_no,email_id) values ('$first_name','$middle_name','$last_name','$mobile_no','$email_id')");
    //  mysql_query("$qry);
    //}
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "there is problem with query";
}
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove `isset()` function because it will return `1` when value come.

Answer (score 3):

You're problem lies in this part:

```
$first_name=isset($_POST['first_name']);
$middle_name=isset($_POST['middle_name']);
$last_name=isset($_POST['last_name']);
$email_id=isset($_POST['email_id']);
$mobile_no=isset($_POST['mobile_no']);
```

`isset` is a function that returns 1 or true if a variable has been initialized/set, that's why. So your solution would be to remove the `isset` function calls.

However if you still want to check whether the `post` variable has been set before assigning it to a variable, I'd suggest using a ternary if statement, which achieves this in one line and looks nice and tidy:

```
$first_name= (isset($_POST['first_name'])) ? $_POST['first_name'] : "";
$middle_name= (isset($_POST['middle_name'])) ? $_POST['middle_name'] : "";
//...
```

This first checks if the `post` variable is set, and if it is it assigns it to the variable. In case it is not set, the variable will be assigned an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `isset` on each of your POST parameters, which will return true or false based on whether the parameter is set or not.  Remove the `isset` calls, and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this:

```
$first_name=isset($_POST['first_name']);
$middle_name=isset($_POST['middle_name']);
$last_name=isset($_POST['last_name']);
$email_id=isset($_POST['email_id']);
$mobile_no=isset($_POST['mobile_no']);
```

to:

```
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$middle_name=$_POST['middle_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$email_id=$_POST['email_id'];
$mobile_no=$_POST['mobile_no'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Isset returns Boolean 0 0r 1. That is the reason you are getting 1 every time it true. Remove the isset from your variables  simply use

```
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$middle_name=$_POST['middle_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$email_id=$_POST['email_id'];
$mobile_no=$_POST['mobile_no'];
```

second thing use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)  because mysql_* has been depricated now

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

     $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$con)
    {
       echo "Connection is not Est"."<br>";
   }
   else
   {
       mysql_select_db("college",$con);

       $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
       $middle_name = $_POST['middle_name'];
       $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
       $email_id = $_POST['email_id'];
       $mobile_no = $_POST['mobile_no'];

       if( $qry=mysql_query("insert into stud_master(fname,mname,lname,mobile_no,email_id) values ('$first_name','$middle_name','$last_name','$mobile_no','$email_id')"){

      echo "success";

      }
      else{
         echo "there is problem with query";
      }
   }
?>
```

A few Notes:
1. Switch over to mysqli rather than using the deprecated mysql
2. Your code as it is, is not secure. Someone could harm your database, as your values are not escaped.

That said, the code above should work.